# Error on input string format not correct

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I have this simple calculation but for some reason I am not picking up where the problem is. I am getting "format input string not correct" error.

This is the code:

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        GridDataItem dataItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;
        if (dataItem["AlternCost"].Text !=null)
        {
            dataItem["TotCost"].Text = ((Convert.ToInt32(dataItem["AlternCost"].Text)) * (Convert.ToDouble(dataItem["Quantity"].Text))).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            dataItem["TotCost"].Text = ((Convert.ToInt32(dataItem["Cost"].Text)) * (Convert.ToDouble(dataItem["Quantity"].Text))).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

The error is on this line:

```
dataItem["TotCost"].Text =
((Convert.ToInt32(dataItem["AlternCost"].Text)) *
(Convert.ToDouble(dataItem["Quantity"].Text))).ToString();
```

This is my stack trace:

> in System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options,
>   NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
>   in System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style,
>   NumberFormatInfo info)    in System.Convert.ToInt32(String value)
>   in xxx_621.RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(Object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
>   in c:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\^^xxxxxxxxxxx -
>   BOM\members\xxx_621.aspx.cs:riga 57    in
>   Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.OnItemDataBound(GridItemEventArgs e)    in
>   Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.CallOnItemDataBound(GridItemEventArgs e)    in
>   Telerik.Web.UI.GridItem.SetupItem(Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem,
>   GridColumn[] columns, ControlCollection rows)    in
>   Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemBuilder.InitializeItem(Int32 dataSourceIndex,
>   String& nextItemHierarchicalIndex, Boolean& itemIsInEditMode)    in
>   Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemBuilder.CreateItems(GridGroupingContext group) 
>   in Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView.CreateItems(IEnumerator enumerator,
>   GridColumn[] columns, ControlCollection controls)    in
>   Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView.CreateControlHierarchy(Boolean
>   useDataSource)    in
>   Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable
>   dataSource, Boolean useDataSource)    in
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable
>   data)    in
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable
>   data)    in
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback)    in
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect()    in
>   Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView.PerformSelect()    in
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind()    in
>   Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView.DataBind()    in
>   Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.DataBind()    in
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound()    in
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls()
>   in System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()    in
>   System.Web.UI.Control.FindControl(String id, Int32 pathOffset)    in
>   System.Web.UI.Control.FindControl(String id)    in
>   Telerik.Web.ChildControlHelper.FindControlRecursive(String ID, Control
>   root)    in Telerik.Web.ChildControlHelper.FindControlRecursive(String
>   ID, Control root)    in
>   Telerik.Web.ChildControlHelper.FindControlRecursive(String ID, Control
>   root)    in
>   Telerik.Web.ChildControlHelper.FindControlRecursive(Control searcher,
>   String ID)    in
>   Telerik.Web.UI.RadAjaxControl.FindControlRecursive(String ID)    in
>   Telerik.Web.UI.RadAjaxControl.OnPagePreRender(Object sender, EventArgs
>   e)    in System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)    in
>   System.Web.UI.Control.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)    in
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()    in
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Can someone please give me a hint on how to solve the problem?

Comment: Please provide value that give error.

Comment: Cost 10000, Quantity 0.123, AlternCost 9900

Comment: What is culture of your application. 0.123 seems to be culprit so check with simple integer value see do you get error.

Comment: @dotnetstep Thanks but that is fine. Is the first think I checked.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942460

Comment: rather than checking if the string != null, maybe you should use IsNullOrEmpty.

Comment: @KevinCook Thanks for the advice. I tested it and the problem is still there!

Comment: Is there any html formatting inside the text that needs to be stripped out?

Comment: @KevinCook no, The data are coming straight from the SQL database. I think I have to look into other possible issues with the RadGrid. Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: Are the controls visible in the grid? If they aren't, you will need to set them to display = false rather than visible = false

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this be:

```
dataItem["TotCost"].Text = ((Convert.ToDouble(dataItem["AlternCost"].Text)) * (Convert.ToDouble(dataItem["Quantity"].Text))).ToString();
```

intead of:

```
dataItem["TotCost"].Text = ((Convert.ToInt32(dataItem["AlternCost"].Text)) * (Convert.ToDouble(dataItem["Quantity"].Text))).ToString();
```

note the Convert.ToDouble in both cases instead of ToInt32 and ToDouble?

Comment: Tried also that. Thanks

Comment: are you doing it on postback?

Comment: The event is on post back by nature